# Frame not closing when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a login page that is my java project and on the login page, the user can choose to create a new account if he hasn't. I managed to open the create account frame when the button is clicked if you see the code below but I cannot close the login JFRAME when the create account button is clicked. In the design view of netbeans, I changed the property of the frame to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE and nothing is happening still. Do let me know of the why is this so, you can refer to the function "CreateAccountNowButtonActionPerformed"

```
package pleasework;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author jacksonseow
 */
public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /*Creates new form login*/
    public login() {
        initComponents();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        mainLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        usernameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtUsername = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        passwordLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtPassword = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        LoginButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        CreateAccountNowButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        dealLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(650, 380));

        mainLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        mainLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        mainLabel.setText("Gracious Givers");

        usernameLabel.setText("Username");

        txtUsername.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtUsernameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        passwordLabel.setText("Password");

        txtPassword.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtPasswordActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        LoginButton.setText("Login");
        LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 102, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("OR");

        CreateAccountNowButton.setText("Create Account Now!");
        CreateAccountNowButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CreateAccountNowButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        dealLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/Users/jacksonseow/Netbeans Images/deal.png")); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(passwordLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(usernameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(txtUsername)
                    .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(221, 221, 221)
                .addComponent(CreateAccountNowButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(229, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(307, 307, 307)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(253, 253, 253)
                .addComponent(dealLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 145, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(231, 231, 231)
                .addComponent(mainLabel)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(244, 244, 244)
                .addComponent(LoginButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(mainLabel)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(dealLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 99, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(usernameLabel)
                    .addComponent(txtUsername, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(passwordLabel))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(LoginButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(CreateAccountNowButton)
                .addGap(16, 16, 16))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtUsernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void txtPasswordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void CreateAccountNowButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        registration reg = new registration();
        reg.setVisible(true);
        //reg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
    }                                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton CreateAccountNowButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton LoginButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel dealLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mainLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel passwordLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtPassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtUsername;
    private javax.swing.JLabel usernameLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Use a JPasswordField instead of a JTextField for the password
2. A better option than creating your own JFrame would be to just build a JPanel with all of your controls (minus "ok-cancel") and use JOptionPane.showConfirmMessage(...) with your JPanel. Doing this, the ok-cancel buttons are automatically handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the current JFrame is not closing because you have not given the command to do so.

In the CreateAccountNowButtonActionPerformed() method, you are creating an instance of the registration JFrame and setting it visible. So, it will show 'reg' JFrame. But, with this operation, you should have written

```
setVisible(false);
```

instead of

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) does the same thing as you have done using the design view. As the method name is self-explanatory, it sets the default close operation, where it is to do nothing or to hide this JFrame or to dispose it or to exit the program. But, in order to apply that action, we need to call some function that uses this property. And this function is setVisible(false).

When you use this method, the default close operation that you have mentioned in the frame property, that will be used.

So, keep the property in the design view as it is, just change the line

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

to

```
setVisible(false);
```

and it will do the desired work. After this change when you run the code and press on the button, it will open the registration JFrame and close current JFrame.

Some advice related to the code : There is one point already mentioned in the other answer that for password you should use JPasswordField and not JTextField. Do follow the same thing. Also, it is better practice to write class name that starts with a captial letter. You should apply the same in both login and registration class names.

Comment: Hi I tried doing what you suggested and to show you, here is the code I changed: private void CreateAccountNowButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        //close();
        registration reg = new registration();
        reg.setVisible(true);   
        setVisible(false);
    }  Ive done this and is still not working, any idea why?

Comment: Can you check if DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE is set in the design options of the login JFrame. If this option is correct, then try dispose() instead of setVisible(false) and check if it works.

Comment: setVisible(false); should do it. Are you sure you're not throwing an exception before calling setVisible(false);? Maybe put a print statement afterwards.

Comment: the option in design view is DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE, and I changed setVisible(false) to dispose(), but it is still not working.

Comment: Do you mind trying the code out in your netbeans ide, idk if its a problem on my side as well.

Comment: Yes.. As per me, either of setVisible(false) with default close operation DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE or dispose() should be working. I checked the code in NetBeans in my laptop and I am able to close the login JFrame.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry I think there's a problem with my netbeans, sometimes when I create a JBUtton I need to run at least 20 times for it to be showing up. Now I am able to close the current frame, thank you for your help.